# Why is the Connection pool cloned here?

Tags: multithreading, rust, r2d2

In this code example, from the [Github page of r2d2](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2#example):

```
fn main() {
    let manager = r2d2_foodb::FooConnectionManager::new("localhost:1234");
    let pool = r2d2::Pool::builder()
        .max_size(15)
        .build(manager)
        .unwrap();

    for _ in 0..20 {
        let pool = pool.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let conn = pool.get().unwrap();
        })
    }
}
```

Why is the `Pool` struct being cloned in the loop?

Comment: your question is "why clone is needed ?" or "why clone is on this line ?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the threads spawned inside the loop need to take ownership of `pool`, as each thread could run for longer than `main`. Referencing `pool` owned by `main` from inside a thread could lead to referencing a value that has already been destroyed if `main` exits while the threads are still running.

Taking ownership of `pool` requires you to clone it each time the loop executes, so each thread has its own copy.

Internally, a `Pool` is an `std::sync::Arc` and the `Clone` implementation simply clones the `Arc`. That is, each clone of `Pool` is just an incremented reference count. As the threads are created, the reference count is increased. When the threads finish, they decrement the reference count by dropping their `Pool`, destroying the underlying connection when the reference count reaches zero.